# Do web pages that change constantly rank higher than pages with static content?

Tags: seo, ranking

We are building car selling website where users can upload their second hand cars to be sold to other interested buyers.

Currently we have a simple form where we ask user the vehicle and personal details before uploading the car on our website.  We want to move up this page's search engine rankings. I just read that freshness or frequently changing pages rank higher in SEO.

What if we start showing customers testimonials somewhere on this page. As these would be randomly picked, would keep on constantly changing, would it help me in improving search engine rankings of this page?

Comment: What are people searching for to get to the page?   Some content is "evergreen".  It doesn't matter to searchers how old it is.  Sometimes older is even better.   Some searches are "query deserves freshness" (QDF).   What people are searching for really matters.

Comment: This answer may help. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/102172/will-putting-a-clock-display-on-a-website-boost-seo/102181#102181

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment, some rich content in some niche ranks with consistency without any changes being made.

And there are may situations where freshness would play an important role like news etc.

To answer more specific to your needs, i would say customer testimonials may not the role of freshness.

Your actual listing pages would be temporary as once the product would be sold or listing will expire, it will be a 404 page mostly and here you need to just work on better user experience.

You can handle freshness in few ways like:

1. You can plan your categories well, where URLs will be permanent and it will gain a lot more weight over time and you may wish to have additional content apart from product listing and you can try to update as and when needed.
2. A blog is very good option to introduce freshness and you can can publish new blogs regularly.

Conclusion: You may not need to over think about freshness, just work on good rich experience for the user and then think about freshness as per above or other methods.